# What is the best practice for parsing retrofit response on android with coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, android-networking

I am trying to figure out what is the best practice for handling a retrofit response.

I provide the retrofit singlton like this:

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .addInterceptor(AuthInterceptor())
      .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
      .build()

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
      .client(okHttpClient)
      .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
      .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
      .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutinesResponseCallAdapterFactory())
      .build()
    
val service = retrofit.create(ShowsService::class.java)
```

The service interface is this:

```
interface ShowsService {

    @GET("popular")
    suspend fun fetchPopularShows(): Response<PopularShows>
}
```

I get a list of shows from API and parse it in a repository like this:

```
override suspend fun getShows(): Result<List<Show>?> {
    val shows = service.fetchPopularShows()
    val body = shows.body()
    val errorBody = shows.errorBody()
    return when {
        body != null -> {
            Result.Success(body.shows)
        }
        errorBody != null -> {
            Result.Error(Exception(errorBody.string()))
        }
        else -> {
            Result.Error(Exception("Unknown error: ${shows.raw().message}"))
        }
    }
}
```

However, this feels very non-kotlin and also would probably result in code duplication eventually, can anyone point me to a sample where this is implemented in the best practice?

Comment: Can i please get some feedback on why this was downvoted?

Comment: I can't speak to why this was downvoted. However, your question is about Retrofit, and there does not appear to be much related to Retrofit in the code sample. And, since Retrofit itself is an external library, your "without external libraries" statement is rather strange. Regardless, it would help if your [mcve] would show how you are configuring Retrofit, how you are defining your Retrofit API, and how this code sample relates to those things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In principle, you could create an `unwrapResponse()` generic function that takes a `Response<T>` and returns a `Result<T?>` and incorporates your algorithm. By eyeball, something like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> unwrapResponse(response: Response<T>): Result<T> {
    val body = response.body()
    val errorBody = response.errorBody()

    return when {
        body != null -> {
            Result.Success(body)
        }
        errorBody != null -> {
            Result.Error(Exception(errorBody.string()))
        }
        else -> {
            Result.Error(Exception("Unknown error: ${response.raw().message}"))
        }
    }
}
```

You could then call `unwrapResponse(service.fetchPopularShows())` to get a `Result<PopularShows>`.

If you really wanted to allow `unwrapResponse()` to return a `Result<List<Show>?>`, you would wind up with something like:

```kotlin
suspend fun <T, R> unwrapResponse(response: Response<T>, unpacker: (T) -> R?): Result<R?> {
    val body = response.body()
    val errorBody = response.errorBody()

    return when {
        body != null -> {
            Result.Success(unpacker(body))
        }
        errorBody != null -> {
            Result.Error(Exception(errorBody.string()))
        }
        else -> {
            Result.Error(Exception("Unknown error: ${response.raw().message}"))
        }
    }
}
```

`unwrapResponse(service.fetchPopularShows()) { it.shows }` would then give your `Result<List<Show>?>`.

Again, this is all by eyeball — adjustments are likely to be needed here.

Comment: Yes this is basically what I was looking for, I'm still struggling on generics, thank you.